# authorize.net Production account accepts test credit card numbers

Tags: authorize.net

i am using arb of authorize.net. I am also in production mode. but when i enter test credit card numbers it accepts on live site and let the user do register. other wrong credit card numbers are not accepted.

if any body has idea, please share with me.

my code is as follows:

```
$_CONFIG['Authorize']['g_apihost'] =    "api.authorize.net";
$_CONFIG['Authorize']['g_apipath'] =    "/xml/v1/request.api";

function create_subscription($name,$amount,$refId,$length,$unit,$startDate,$totalOccurrences,$cardNumber,$expirationDate,$firstName,$lastName,$email,$trialOccurrences=0,$trialAmount=0){


//echo $name."<br>".$amount."<br>".$refId."<br>".$length."<br>".$unit."<br>".$startDate."<br>".$totalOccurrences."<br>".$cardNumber."<br>".$expirationDate."<br>".$firstName."<br>".$lastName."<br>".$trialOccurrences."<br>".$trialAmount;exit;
//API SETTING

global $_CONFIG, $mySession;

$loginname=$_CONFIG['Authorize']['g_loginname'];
$transactionkey=$_CONFIG['Authorize']['g_transactionkey'];


$host = $_CONFIG['Authorize']['g_apihost'] ; 



$path = "/xml/v1/request.api";

//END OF API SETTING

//build xml to post
$content =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
        "<ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">" .
        "<merchantAuthentication>".
        "<name>" . $loginname . "</name>".
        "<transactionKey>" . $transactionkey . "</transactionKey>".
        "</merchantAuthentication>".
        "<refId>" . $refId . "</refId>".
        "<subscription>".
        "<name>" . $name . "</name>".
        "<paymentSchedule>".
        "<interval>".
        "<length>". $length ."</length>".
        "<unit>". $unit ."</unit>".
        "</interval>".
        "<startDate>" . $startDate . "</startDate>".
        "<totalOccurrences>". $totalOccurrences . "</totalOccurrences>".
        "<trialOccurrences>". $trialOccurrences . "</trialOccurrences>".
        "</paymentSchedule>".
        "<amount>". $amount ."</amount>".
        "<trialAmount>" . $trialAmount . "</trialAmount>".
        "<payment>".
        "<creditCard>".
        "<cardNumber>" . $cardNumber . "</cardNumber>".
        "<expirationDate>" . $expirationDate . "</expirationDate>".
        "</creditCard>".
        "</payment>".
        "<customer>".
        "<email>" . $email . "</email>".
        "</customer>".
        "<billTo>".
        "<firstName>". $firstName . "</firstName>".
        "<lastName>" . $lastName . "</lastName>".
        "</billTo>".
        "</subscription>".
        "</ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest>";

//send the xml via curl
$response = send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content);
    if ($response){
    list ($refId, $resultCode, $code, $text, $subscriptionId) =parse_return($response);
    $re['refId']=$refId;
    $re['resultCode']=$resultCode;
    $re['code']=$code;
    $re['text']=$text;
    $re['subscriptionId']=$subscriptionId;

    }else{
    $re['refId']=$refId;
    $re['resultCode']=$resultCode;
    $re['code']=$code;
    $re['text']=$text;
    $re['subscriptionId']=$subscriptionId;

    }

    return $re;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If test credit card numbers are being accepted then you are not using the live server or are in test mode. Doublecheck your code and verify that you haven't hardcoded the test URL or set test mode anywhere. It doesn't look like all of your code is displayed in your question as I don't see where your cURL code anywhere.

Comment: function send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content)
{
 $posturl = "https://" . $host . $path;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 return $response;
}  respected john above is my code for curl

Answer (score 3):

Authorize.NET accepts test credit card numbers in live mode. I verified this customer support, the customer support manager, and their devs. But they assured me the transactions would get declined, which is correct. Unfortunately, not as useful as one would hope.

Comment: Yes confirmed this is true, it's crazy